UnityEditor.AndroidManifest.SetFixedWindowSize Error on build when Firebase Messaging is added
Every time I add Firebase Messaging SDK to my project and build it on android, it fails and returns the error below.
Unity Version: 2020.3.47f1
Firebase SDK Version: firebase_unity_sdk_11.6.0
Target Platform: Android
Additional Info:
I have Firebase Auth, Firestore, and Storage on my project.
This error only shows up when I add Firebase Messaging.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnityEditor.AndroidManifest.SetFixedWindowSize (System.String activity, System.Int32 defaultWidth, System.Int32 defaultHeight, System.Int32 minimumWidth, System.Int32 minimumHeight) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.PatchLibraryManifest (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String manifest) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <22b0bbbaead14b9cb1b4d2a9a9cd4275>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <3e401efa0ce4422582abd640a807e261>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I tried opening a previous version of my project and creating an empty project. The error only occurs when adding Firebase Messaging SDK is added.
